# pysnmp send Notification not working - return None

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp, snmp-trap

I develop two programs which are an SNMP agent and an SNMP manager, with the PySnmp library:

- agent : receives GET requests, generates Notifications (trap / inform)
- manager : generates GET requests, receives Notifications (and answers to inform).

The different 'target' and 'user' are created by generic methods.

I managed to make these programs work with SNMPv2 (community system) from PySnmp, but I can't make them work with SNMPv3 (user system, authentication and encryption).

When the function that is supposed to send the notification runs, it returns 'None', so it tells me that something has gone wrong. But no error is triggered. Also, with the tcpdump tool, I can see that no udp frames are coming out of the agent.
On the other hand, my SNMP agent and my SNMP manager are able to make GET requests and to respond to these requests.

The GET and TRAP / INFORM are done on objects coming from a custom MIB, which I include in my programs.

The agent and the manager are launched in two different containers (Docker), with a network between the two, and a DNS resolution of the names 'agent' and 'manager' to contact each other.

So my question is : Why doesn't the Notification send? How to correct this problem ?
If you see any other errors in the code, don't hesitate.

Thanks in advance.

Unfortunately, my problem may come from the way I use the method that generates a notification, but mostly from the user and target configurations I make before. So I give you the code that creates these user and target.

In order for you to be able to run the code on your computer, I prefer to give you some examples of code that allow the agent and the manager to work together. These following codes only allow to make GET and NOTIFY.

However, here is the piece of code that does not work.

```
self.notif_origin.sendVarBinds(
    self.engine,
    str(target_name+'_inform_notif'),
    None,
    'context',
    [((object_id), None)],
    self.inform_cb
)
```

agent's code (only the code useful for understanding the problem). Normally the code should be able to run on your computers. Here you can find out how I create a user and a target.

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, ntforg, context
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, rfc1902, error
from pysnmp.proto.rfc1902 import ObjectName, Null, OctetString
from socket import gethostbyname, gaierror
from collections import namedtuple

InetAddr = namedtuple('InetAddr', 'IP PORT')
User = namedtuple('User', 'NAME AUTHKEY PRIVKEY')

class Agent():
    def __init__(self, address, user, security_engine_i) :
        self.engine = engine.SnmpEngine(OctetString(hexValue=str(security_engine_id)))
        self.context = context.SnmpContext(self.engine)
        self.security_engine_id = security_engine_id
        self.users = {}
        self.targets = {}

        config.addTransport(
            self.engine,
            udp.domainName,
            udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode((address.IP, address.PORT))
        )

        try:
            config.addV3User(
                self.engine,
                str(user.NAME),
                config.usmHMAC384SHA512AuthProtocol, str(user.AUTHKEY),
                config.usmAesCfb256Protocol, str(user.PRIVKEY)
            )
        except error.WrongValueError as _:
            return None
        config.addTargetParams(
            self.engine,
            'params',
            str(user.NAME),
            'authPriv'
        )
        config.addTransport(
            self.engine,
            udp.domainName+(1,),
            udp.UdpSocketTransport().openClientMode()
        )
        config.addContext(
            self.engine,
            'context'
        )
        config.addVacmUser(
            self.engine,
            3,
            str(user.NAME),
            'authPriv',
            notifySubTree=(1,3,6,1,4,1,1581)
        )

        self.import_mib()
        cmdrsp.GetCommandResponder(self.engine, self.context)
        self.notif_origin = ntforg.NotificationOriginator()

    def import_mib(self):
        self.mib_builder =self.engine.msgAndPduDsp.mibInstrumController.mibBuilder
        self.mib_builder.addMibSources(builder.DirMibSource('/app/mibs'))
        self.mib_builder.loadModules()
        self.mib_view_controller = view.MibViewController(self.mib_builder)

    def add_user(self, user):
        if str(user.NAME) not in self.users.keys():
            try:
                config.addV3User(
                    self.engine,
                    str(user.NAME),
                    config.usmHMAC384SHA512AuthProtocol, str(user.AUTHKEY),
                    config.usmAesCfb256Protocol, str(user.PRIVKEY)
                )
            except error.WrongValueError as _:
                return False
            config.addVacmUser(
                self.engine,
                3,
                str(user.NAME),
                'authPriv',
                (1,3,6,1,4,1,1581)
            )
            self.users[str(user.NAME)] = [str(user.AUTHKEY), str(user.PRIVKEY)]
            return True
        return False

    def add_target(self, target_name, address):
        if str(target_name) not in self.targets.keys():
            try:
                address_ip = gethostbyname(str(address.IP))
            except gaierror:
                return False
            config.addTargetAddr(
                self.engine,
                str(target_name+'_inform_add'),
                udp.domainName+(1,),
                (str(address_ip), int(address.PORT)),
                'params',
                tagList='inform_tag'
            )
            config.addNotificationTarget(
                self.engine,
                str(target_name+'_inform_notif'),
                'filter',
                'inform_tag',
                'inform'
            )
            self.targets[str(target_name)] = [str(address.IP), int(address.PORT)]
            return True
        return False

    def convert(self, object):
        try:
            if object[0].isnumeric():
                object_id = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity(object).loadMibs('MIB-DAT')
            else:
                object_id = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity('MIB-DAT', object, 0)
            object_id.resolveWithMib(self.mib_view_controller)
            return object_id
        except error.SmiError:
            return None

    def get(self, object):
        object_id = self.convert(object)
        if object_id != None:
            var_bind = self.context.getMibInstrum('').readVars([(ObjectName(object_id), Null(''))])
            return var_bind[0][1]
        return None

    def set(self, object, value):
        object_id = self.convert(object)
        if object_id != None:
            try:
                var_bind = self.context.getMibInstrum('').writeVars([(ObjectName(object_id), OctetString(value))])
                return var_bind[0][1]
            except error.WrongValueError:
                return False
        return None

    def inform(self, target_name, object):
        if str(target_name) in self.targets.keys():
            object_id = self.convert(object)
            if object_id != None:
                self.notif_origin.sendVarBinds(
                    self.engine,
                    str(target_name+'_inform_notif'),
                    None,
                    'context',
                    [((object_id), None)],
                    self.inform_cb
                )
                notif_num = self.get('notif_num')
                self.set('notif_num', notif_num+1)
                return True
            return False
        return False

    def inform_cb(self, engine, request_handle, err_indication, err_status, err_index, binds, cb_ctx):
        print(f'Notification \'{request_handle}\', status - \'{err_indication and err_indication or "delivered"}\'')

    def run(self):
        self.debuger()
        self.engine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)
        try:
            self.engine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
        finally:
            self.engine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
```

An example of main() launching the agent :

```
from threading import Thread
from agent_snmp import Agent, InetAddr, User

def main():
    security_engine_id = '8000000001020304'
    agent_add = InetAddr('agent', 160) # IP = DNS resolution
    agent_user = User('agent_user', 'agent_authkey', 'agent_privkey')

    agent = Agent(agent_add, agent_user, security_engine_id)
    thread_agent = Thread(target=agent.run)

    manager_user = User('manager_user', 'manager_authkey', 'manager_privkey')
    agent.add_user(manager_user)
    manager_add = InetAddr('manager', 161) # IP = DNS resolution
    agent.add_target('manager_target', manager_add)

    thread_agent.start()
    # Then call the agent methods you want

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

manager's code (for the curious):

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdgen, ntfrcv
from pysnmp.smi import builder, rfc1902, error, view
from socket import gethostbyname, gaierror
from collections import namedtuple

InetAddr = namedtuple('InetAddr', 'IP PORT')
User = namedtuple('User', 'NAME AUTHKEY PRIVKEY')

class Manager():
    def __init__(self, user, address):
        self.engine = engine.SnmpEngine()
        self.targets = {}
        self.users = {}

        try:
            config.addV3User(
                self.engine,
                str(user.NAME),
                config.usmHMAC384SHA512AuthProtocol, str(user.AUTHKEY),
                config.usmAesCfb256Protocol, str(user.PRIVKEY)
            )
        except error.WrongValueError as _:
                return False
        config.addTargetParams(
            self.engine,
            'params',
            str(user.NAME),
            'authPriv'
        )
        config.addTransport(
            self.engine,
            udp.domainName,
            udp.UdpSocketTransport().openClientMode()
        )

        config.addTransport(
            self.engine,
            udp.domainName+(1,),
            udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode((address.IP, address.PORT))
        )

        self.import_mib()
        ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(self.engine, self.inform_cb)

    def import_mib(self):
        self.mib_builder = self.engine.msgAndPduDsp.mibInstrumController.mibBuilder
        self.mib_builder.addMibSources(builder.DirMibSource('/app/mibs'))
        self.mib_view_controller = view.MibViewController(self.mib_builder)

    def add_target(self, target_name, address):
        if str(target_name) not in self.targets.keys():
            try:
                address_ip = gethostbyname(str(address.IP))
            except gaierror:
                return False
            config.addTargetAddr(
                self.engine,
                str(target_name),
                udp.domainName,
                (str(address_ip), int(address.PORT)),
                'params'
            )
            self.targets[str(target_name)] = [str(address.IP), int(address.PORT)]
            return True
        return False

    def add_user(self, user, security_engine_id):
        if str(user.NAME) not in self.users.keys():
            try:
                config.addV3User(
                    self.engine,
                    str(user.NAME),
                    config.usmHMAC384SHA512AuthProtocol, str(user.AUTHKEY),
                    config.usmAesCfb256Protocol, str(user.PRIVKEY)
                    # OctetString(hexValue=str(security_engine_id))
                )
            except error.WrongValueError as _:
                return False
            self.users[str(user.NAME)] = [str(user.AUTHKEY), str(user.PRIVKEY), str(security_engine_id)]
            return True
        return False

    def convert(self, object):
        try:
            if object[0].isnumeric():
                object_id = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity(object).loadMibs('MIB-DAT')
            else:
                object_id = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity('MIB-DAT', object, 0)
            object_id.resolveWithMib(self.mib_view_controller)
            return object_id
        except error.SmiError:
            return None

    def get(self, target_name, object):
        if str(target_name) in self.targets.keys():
            object_id = self.convert(object)
            if object_id != None:
                cmdgen.GetCommandGenerator().sendVarBinds(
                    self.engine,
                    str(target_name),
                    None,
                    '',
                    [((object_id), None)],
                    self.get_cb
                )
                return True
            return None
        return False

    def get_cb(self, engine_observer, request_handle, err_indication, err_status, err_index, binds, cb_ctx):
        if err_indication:
            print(err_indication)
        elif err_status and err_status != 2:
            print(f'\'{err_status}\' at \'{err_index and binds[int(err_index) - 1][0] or "?"}\'')
        else:
            for oid, val in binds:
                print(f'\'{oid}\' = \'{val}\'')

    def inform_cb(self, engine, state_reference, context_engine_id, context_name, binds, cb_ctx):
        print(f'Notification from Context_engine_id \'{context_engine_id}\', Context_name \'{context_name}\'')
        for name, val in binds:
            print(f'\'{name}\' = \'{val}\'')

    def run(self):
        self.debuger()
        self.engine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)
        try:
            self.engine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
        finally:
            self.engine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
```

An example of main() launching the manager :

```
from threading import Thread
from manager_snmp import Manager, InetAddr, User

def main():    
    manager_user = User('manager_user', 'manager_authkey', 'manager_privkey')
    manager_add = InetAddr('manager', 161)
    manager = Manager(manager_user, manager_add)
    thread_manager = Thread(target=manager.run)

    agent_add = InetAddr('agent', 160)
    manager.add_target('agent_target', agent_add)
    agent_user = User('agent_user', 'agent_authkey', 'agent_privkey')
    manager.add_user(agent_user, '8000000001020304')

    thread_manager.start()
    # Then call the manager methods you want

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is a part of the custom MIB I use :

```
MIB-DAT DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

org            OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { iso 3 }  --  "iso" = 1
dod            OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { org 6 }
internet       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { dod 1 }
private        OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { internet 4 }
enterprises    OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { private 1 }

entreprise OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { enterprises 1581 }
dat OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { entreprise 1 }
notification OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { dat 1 }

notif_dat NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    OBJECTS {notif_str}
    STATUS  mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "notif du DAT"
    ::= { notification 1 }

notif_str OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(78))
    ACCESS      write-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "String total de la notif"
    DEFVAL { "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" }
    ::= { notification 2 }

notif_num OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      INTEGER (0..9999)
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "Numéro d'instance de la notif"
    ::= { notification 3 }

notif_type OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(1))
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "Type de la notif"
    DEFVAL { "E" }
    ::= { notification 4 }

dat_date OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(10))
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "date sur le dat"
    ::= { dat 2 } 

dat_time OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(9))
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "Temps sur le dat"
    ::= { dat 3 } 

nus OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      INTEGER (0..9999)
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "Numéro de série de l'appareil"
    ::= { dat 4 }

EtaValue ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION "mapping eta"
    SYNTAX INTEGER {
        V (1),
        S (2),
        H (3),
        A (4),
        M (5),
        N (6)
    }

eta OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      EtaValue
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "ETA de la MIB"
    DEFVAL { 6 }
    ::= { dat 5 }

ModValue ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION "mapping mod"
    SYNTAX INTEGER {
        R (1),
        F (2)
    }

mod OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      ModValue
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "MOD de la MIB"
    DEFVAL { 1 }
    ::= { dat 6 }

TinValue ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION "mapping tin"
    SYNTAX INTEGER {
        M (1),
        E (2),
        R (3),
        A (4)
    }

tin OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      TinValue
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "TIN de la MIB"
    DEFVAL { 4 }
    ::= { dat 7 }

SseValue ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION "mapping sse"
    SYNTAX INTEGER {
        A (1),
        B (2),
        C (3),
        D (4),
        E (5),
        F (6),
        G (7),
        H (8),
        I (9),
        J (10),
        K (11),
        L (12),
        M (13),
        N (14),
        O (15),
        P (16),
        Q (17),
        R (18),
        S (19),
        T (20),
        U (21),
        V (22),
        W (23),
        X (24),
        Y (25),
        Z (26)
    }

sse OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      SseValue
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "SSE de la MIB"
    DEFVAL { 1 }
    ::= { dat 8 }

cod OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      INTEGER (1..999)
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "COD de la MIB"
    DEFVAL { 1 }
    ::= { dat 9 }

clp OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      INTEGER (0..5)
    ACCESS      read-only
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "CLP de la MIB"
    ::= { dat 10 }

msg OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      OCTET STRING (SIZE(31))
    ACCESS      read-write
    STATUS      mandatory
    DESCRIPTION
        "String libre"
    DEFVAL { "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" }
    ::= { dat 11 }

END
```

To put the MIB in place, you must first convert it into a format that PySnmp can understand with the mibdump tool, then place it in the location indicated in the 'import_mib()' method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ContextName was not automatically bind with the VacmUser, so the contextName had to be added by hand.

```
config.addVacmUser(
    self.engine,
    3,
    str(user.NAME),
    'authPriv',
    notifySubTree=(1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 1581),
    contextName='context'
)
```